# Convert string to datetime-javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

i am looking to convert a date in string in javascript/jquery like '20/11/2013' to datetime for code behind like 2013-11-20 00:00:00.000 to be passed to the SQL.I cant add any extra jquery plugin to achieve this.

Comment: do you really need to convert it clientside with javascript? Could you pass it to your C# and convert it there?

Comment: You haven't to invent a bicycle ;) (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use with this.

```
new Date('2013-04-13');
```

or

```
new Date('2013-04-13T11:51:00');
```

Comment: var a = "2013-11-20T00:00:00.000";
alert(new Date(a));

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "2013-11-20 00:00:00.000";
var b = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" ")).split('/');

alert (new Date(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with two way

```
var a = "2013-11-20 00:00:00.000";
var b = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" ")).split('-');

alert(new Date(b));
alert(new Date(b).toDateString());
```

First value returns long date
second value returns sort date

Answer (score 0):

try this in javascript

```
a = "20/11/2013";
var b = a.split('/');
alert( new Date(b[2],b[1],b[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value from javascript you can use hidden field.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function abc()
{
  var str="datetime value";
  document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=str;
}


</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="abc()"  Text="Button"
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Get the string
   string datetime=Hidden1.Value
   //Convert to datetime
   //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DateTime Dt = DateTime.ParseExact(line[i], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```